# Data interpreted incorrectly when opening NetCDF file in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, netcdf

I'm trying to open a NetCDF file with some current data on a polar stereographic projection in ArcMap, but the data are not displayed correctly. The only obvious problem I can see is that ArcMap seems to be interepreting some of the global attributes incorrectly. For example, in ncdump it says

```
:false_easting = 2384800.f ;
```

Whereas in ArcMap it says

```
False_Easting 1.890518526342814e-273
```

Is there anything I can do to ensure the attributes are read correctly? I thought the point of a format like NetCDF was that it would specify both the data and the data type in a standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like ArcMap interprets this variable as a double precision float, even if it is saved as a single float. At least it is read correctly when I changed it to a double in the NetCDF file.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few potential problems:

There are established Climate and Forecast (CF) Conventions for storing projection information in NetCDF files (http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/documents/cf-conventions/1.6/apf.html) but that doesn't mean that people always follow them. Check to make sure the input NetCDF file you are trying to use follows the conventions.

Some of the less common projections haven't been used that much in NetCDF, so it's possible that ArcMAP is just not handling the conversion of parameters correctly.  You could try exporting some polar stereographic raster data from ArcMAP as NetCDF, and compare the conventions to the NetCDF file that is giving you problems.